# Emacs yasnippet - insert snippet on keystroke

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, code-snippets, yasnippet

Is there a way to easily insert a snippet when a certain keybinding is activated? AFAICT, official documentation suggests setting: `#binding:`  directive, smth like this:

```
#name : <p>...</p>
#binding: C-c C-c C-m
# --
<p>`(when yas/prefix "\n")`$0`(when yas/prefix "\n")`</p>
```

It's not working for me, however. Any ideas on what may cause the problem?

**EDIT**

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.0.93.1 with Yasnippet grabbed from [GitHub repo](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet).

Comment: In what mode are you trying the binding? What version of Emacs and YASnippet are you using?

Comment: What does "C-h k C-c C-c C-m" print?

Comment: BTW `C-c C-c` is generally taken by major modes, IMO one better not use it as a prefix

Comment: @N.N. I was trying to use it in `html-mode` (actually `nxhtml-mode`). @Thomas, `describe-key` is interrupted after `C-c C-c`, but nothing happens if I change the binding. @kindahero, yes I'm aware of that, this stuff is from official Yasnippet page.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you have a recent version of Yasnippet. The snippet you provide works (almost) perfectly with a recent version of [Yasnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet).

The reason I said "almost" is that the `yas/prefix` technique was not working at all due to a bug which I fixed just now (referenced this StackOverflow link in the commit)

So using `C-c C-c m` will expand `<p></p>` and using `C-u C-c C-c m` will expand `<p></p>`

If you still have problems you can use the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues) for these issues

Comment: Nope, it's still not working for me. Will continue this rant on GitHub.

Comment: Damn, it was as easy as putting the snippet in `nxhtml-mode` folder. Facepalm.